# imshow resize + count white pixels

Tags: python, opencv

This is a simple program to read video files from your computer. My original video is 1080p resolution. When I run the code, the program's screen (imshow) exceeds my pc's screen which is only 720p. How to resize it from 1080p to 720 or 480p. Second question, how to find the number of pixels in the screen?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('apple.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cv2.resize()` to resize the image before `imshow()` to fit in the screen, and to get the total number of pixels in the Mat you can use `gray.shape[0] * gray.shape[1]`

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('apple.mp4')

total_white_pixels_in_video_sequence = 0

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx = 0.5, fy = 0.5, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    print "No. of pixels : ", gray.shape[0] * gray.shape[1]
    # Counting the number of pixels with given value
    total_white_pixels_in_video_sequence += np.count_nonzero(gray == 255)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print "total_white_pixels_in_video_sequence : ", total_white_pixels_in_video_sequence
```

Comment: I have an additional function. It is background subtraction. Im only interested in the white pixels. How to get the number.

Comment: Added to the answer, not tested though, verify it

Comment: numpy is not defined. something wrong with  numpy.count_nonzero(gray == 255)

Comment: You imported the `numpy`  as `np`

Comment: Last question, since it is a while loop. How do we get the total of white pixels in the end. np.count_nonzero(gray == 255) + something?

Comment: Edited as per query