# Errors in using cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

Tags: python, opencv, pixel, video-processing

In an attempt to compute the number of white pixels in each frame of my animation(white circle moving on black frame), I came across this [OpenCV function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521571/imshow-resize-count-white-pixels):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('control_random.mp4')

total_white_pixels_in_video_sequence = 0

while(cap.isOpened()):

    # Take each frame of the video.
    _, frame = cap.read()


    #print(frame)

    # Convert BGR to gray
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    print ("No. of pixels : ", gray.shape[0] * gray.shape[1])

    # Counting the number of pixels with given value: define range of gray color in HSV
    total_white_pixels_in_video_sequence += np.count_nonzero(gray == 255)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print ("total_white_pixels_in_video_sequence : ", total_white_pixels_in_video_sequence)
```

I got the first error :

> error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

I found here two possible solutions to this error:

1. I tried `gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(frame), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`, but I still got an error:

> TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'

2. Then I tried `gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.UMat(frame), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`, and got the error:

> AttributeError: 'cv2.UMat' object has no attribute 'shape'

When I print frame, I get an array of zeros: [[[0 0 0] [0 0 0]   [0 0 0]...

I checked the path, and it is in the same directory of this code. So the path shouldn't be a problem?

I checked the integrity of my video file, following this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4) recommendations, and I tried this command in my Linux terminal: `ffmpeg -v error -i control_random.mp4 -f null - 2>error.log` but it is not printing anything.

My question: is it worth it to debug this, or is there another way to compute the number of white pixels per frame. I can also do it while I am creating the animation, and before generating the video.

This piece of my code create my animation:

```
for Nframes in range(8):

    with shader:  

        transformations['view_matrix'] = get_view_matrix(z=scrDist)
        transformations.send()


        for sphere in spheres:

            # Update Spheres Positions
            sphere.position.x += sphere.dx
            sphere.position.y += sphere.dy
            sphere.position.z += sphere.dz

            # Draw the spheres
            sphere.draw()

    # Get the back buffer frames
    win.getMovieFrame(buffer='back')

    win.flip()
```

Your help is highly appreciated and desperately needed. Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Cv Error: (-215:Assertion failed) !\_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121013/open-cv-error-215assertion-failed-src-empty-in-function-cvcvtcolor)

Comment: @HansHirse In that link his image was None. My image is not None, it is a matrix of zeros. I actually don't know what that means...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you had this error at different time points and that's what's confusing here. The original error probably happen in the end of the video.

At least we can say for sure that in the end of the video this code will output an error because `_, frame = cap.read()` will return frame=None in the end.

Therefore to avoid your problem you have to read the returned value "_" and break if it's False (indicating that no frame have been acquired).

Maybe you used the while loop because the number of frames is kind of weird to get, you have to use:

```
number_of_frames = video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
```

This allows to use a regular `for` loop and keep this boolean for error cases.
Here is the updated code, it works with one of my mp4.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('control_random.mp4')
total_white_pixels_in_video_sequence = 0

if cap.isOpened():

    number_of_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

    for frame_number in range(number_of_frames):
        # Take each frame of the video.
        success, frame = cap.read()

        if not success:
            raise Exception('Failed to read the frame number: {}'.format(frame_number))

        print('{} / {}'.format(frame_number, number_of_frames))

        # Convert BGR to gray
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        print("No. of pixels : ", gray.shape[0] * gray.shape[1])

        # Counting the number of pixels with given value: define range of gray color in HSV
        total_white_pixels_in_video_sequence += np.count_nonzero(gray == 255)

        cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print("total_white_pixels_in_video_sequence : ", total_white_pixels_in_video_sequence)
```

Also note that you can test separately the conversion of fully black images:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.zeros((256,256,3), dtype=np.ubyte), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

I think that your trial 1. fails because BGR images are 8u images, so it doesn't accept floats.
For your trial 2, note that opencv usually works with numpy arrays (as in zeros example above).

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks very much for your answer and clarifications! I tried out your code, and I got the error: `NameError: name 'cap' is not defined`. I imported cv2 prior to running this code. Are you using the OpenCV that is included in Python 3?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the first line. This error means that it doesn't know the variable cap. I edited.

Comment: Thanks, no errors thrown! However, it is printing the same number of pixels for each frame (1000000), which I found suspicious. To test whether it was really computing the number of white pixels per frame, I created a video with no white circles in it, it only displays the black background for 200 frames, and I am getting the same number of white pixels (1000000) per frame, when it should be equal to 0. However, the total number of white pixels is accurate (0). There might be a problem only with the calculation of white pixels per frame, and not with the total of white pixels.

Comment: You don't print the number of white pixels, you only print the number of pixels. You have to print ```np.count_nonzero(gray == 255)```.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I've learnt more thanks to you!